# Como puedo filtar una tabla con datos de otra en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos columnas con fechas y horas. Quisiera tomar todos los datos de otra tabla que se encuentren entre las horas de la columna ort y ocas.
Por ejemplo todos los datos entre:
El 1/1/2012  9:04 a las 1/1/2012 18:12
Y 2/1/2012  9:04 a las 2/1/2012 18:13
etc etc

[image: Fechas en las que filtrar datos]

[image: Tabla a filtrar]

```
select * FROM camarinas
WHERE  data
 between (select ort from ort_ocas) 
 and (select ocas from ort_ocas);
```

Da error 1242 retorna mas de una fila

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento, _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Comment: no se si son ideas mias pero el Ort y el Ocas son campos de fechas?

Comment: hablas de 2 tablas y solo muestras 1 tenemos que adivinar la segunda tabla???

Comment: con esta herramienta puedes enseñarnos tu estrucutra y un ejemplo funcional http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: ¿Y cual es la relación entre `ort_ocas` y `camarinas`? Por cierto el error es que el between espera un único valor y el select esta retornando más de una fila

Comment: que tengo qeu seleccionar los valores del campo data que se encuentre entre los campos ort y ocas de la tabla ort_ocas

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero lo que te pregunto es como se relacionan cada fila, ¿por `Id`?

Comment: son tablas independientes, no tienen relacion como tal. Una es una tabla de datos de sensores y la otra una tabal de cuando amacene y cuando anochece. Quiero los datos solo cuando es de dia entre ort y ocas

Comment: Ok, entonces tienes un problema de concepto, hay un montón de filas  en `ocas`, ¿pero como determinas un rango horario? ¿O elijes una fila, o la minima y máxima  lectura o que cumpla con alguna de todas las lecturas?

Comment: Por cada fila ort es el minimo y ocas el maximo dario. Eso seria para todas las filas. Yo hice el codigo linea por linea pero no es el deber. https://imgur.com/a/7zvAje3

Answer (score 1):

Cuando trabajes con bases de datos en SQL, tienes que pensar en conjuntos, no registro a registro:

```
SELECT * FROM camarinas
  WHERE `data` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `data` FROM camarinas
      JOIN ort_ocas
      ON `data` BETWEEN Ort AND Ocas  
  );
```

A partir de este dataset de ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE ort_ocas(
  Id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Ort datetime,
  Ocas datetime
  );
CREATE TABLE camarinas(
  Id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `data` datetime
  );
INSERT INTO ort_ocas (Ort, Ocas) VALUES
  ('2012-01-01 9:04','2012-01-01 18:12'),
  ('2012-01-02 9:04','2012-01-02 18:13');
INSERT INTO camarinas (data) VALUES
  ('2012-01-01 8:00'),
  ('2012-01-01 10:00'),
  ('2012-01-02 7:00'),
  ('2012-01-02 15:00'),
  ('2012-01-02 19:00');
```

Obtendrías este resultado: https://dbfiddle.uk/nkW9zDsB

```
+----+---------------------+
| Id | data                |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2012-01-01 10:00:00 |
|  4 | 2012-01-02 15:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Si, como comentas, tienes muchos datos, igual sería buena opción indexar los campos implicados en la consulta:

```
ALTER TABLE camarinas ADD INDEX(`data`);
ALTER TABLE ort_ocas ADD INDEX(Ort), ADD INDEX(Ocas);
```

Si tus problemas de rendimiento persisten, puedes probar a trabajar con versiones más reducidas de tu tabla `camarinas`:

```
CREATE TABLE camarinas_201201
SELECT * FROM camarinas
  WHERE YEAR(`data`)=2012
  AND MONTH(`data`)=1;
```

Y lanzar tu consulta con esta tabla copiada en vez de con la original.

Comment: Me da este error "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query" no se si es porque tengo mas de 2 millones de datos en camarinas

Comment: Eso es porque te has desconectado del servidor, vuelve a intentarlo :) Si ves que tarda mucho, créate índices como te indico en la ampliación de la respuesta

Comment: 16:40:28 ALTER TABLE camarinas ADD INDEX(`data`) Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 30.000 sec
me sigue igual

Comment: De hecho, hago una consulta con 100k y me da la misma respuesta

Comment: Igual se ha desconectado pero ha continuado creando el índice, reinténtalo un poco más tarde a ver si ha hecho algo entretanto... Crear un índice de una tabla tan grande le llevará más de 30 segundos

Comment: La verdad es que nada.
Hize algo parecido pero de forma ineficiente https://imgur.com/a/7zvAje3

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer tablas de menos registros? Te amplío la respuesta con la propuesta

Answer (score 0):

Tu query no funciona porque la clausula between acepta un valor o una relación 1:1, cómo mencionaba patricio-moracho te falta alguna manera de relacionar las dos tablas, para que se entienda a que fila de ort_ocas hace referencia cada registro.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).